# More efficient RSA using Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

Is there a way to increase the efficiency of the RSA algorithm by incorporating elements of the Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Comment: There is a good explanation [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2575/chinese-remainder-theorem-and-rsa). Also, there are several other questions on this site related to the subject.

Comment: Thank you. I will check them out.